# Conditional exception raising in a flow block

Tags: scala, akka, future, continuations, dataflow

While using Akka's data-flow DSL, I have twice encountered a need to throw an exception inside future, conditionally. This is how I am doing it:

```
flow {
  // ...
  if (someCond)
    shiftUnit(throw new SomeException)
  else
    Future().apply()
  // ...
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

The approach seems correct (although my knowledge is a bit rusty), you can even leave out the other branch, the following works for me (Scala 2.10.1):

```
flow { if (x == 2) shiftUnit(throw new Exception) }
```

which results in a `Future[Unit]`.

Comment: I also have code like `if (someCond) {
        methodReturningFuture(product)()
      } else {
        Future().apply()
      }`. Can I drop the `else` branch here somehow?

Comment: No, you need to return the right thing (which above was Unit). What is the value which needs to be produced in the false branch? A shorter way to wrap that would be Future.successful(x) (or failed, for that matter).

Comment: Then you can create one using `Future.successful(())`, which saves you a round-trip to the thread pool.